# Can we Get list of Voices(Voice Guidance texts) for the Route TBT info ,So that I can voice these values On my own

Tags: android, here-api

From Play Text Delegated function I am getting text to speak when where plat text triggered from Here maps, But I want to call Play-text on my own so I need to text speak.Can we get this list before navigation?
Please find image for better understanding.
[Route With Directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWqgM.jpg)

Comment: There is no such API in mSDK. But all needed information exists (in the class Maneuver - type of maneuver, direction, street name).
You can obtain the list of maneuvers and generate needed text.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API in mSDK. But all needed information exists (in the class Maneuver - type of maneuver, direction, street name). You can obtain the list of maneuvers and generate needed text.